# Linux 2.6.24 kernel compilation error .size expression for copy_user_generic_c does not evaluate to a constant

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

while compiling Linux 2.6.24 kernel i am getting error

```
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/linux/compile.h
  AS      arch/x86/lib/copy_user_64.o
  /tmp/ccAD8iYi.s: Assembler messages:
  /tmp/ccAD8iYi.s: Error: .size expression for copy_user_generic_c does not evaluate to a constant
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/lib/copy_user_64.o] Error 1
make: *** [arch/x86/lib] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I am using gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
I didn't face any error during compilation of Linux 3.12 kernel.

Comment: look here http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/make-bzimage-error-936857/

Answer (score 2):

you should find arch/x86/lib/copy_user_64.S ,change the END(copy_user_generic_c) into END(copy_user_generic_string) in the file,to keep the same  variable in the ENTRY(copy_user_generic_string).